# issues with linphone library in android when using windows machine

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-ndk, linphone

I'm new working with linphone. I have spent two days trying to compile linphone in eclipse but i always have a lot of errors, I have also read README file more than once, but always it doeasn't work, so is that possible to use linphone as a jar library file without all these configuration or not??? and if not please anyone can provide me a step by step tutorial of using linphone to build android application on windows machine

Thanks

Comment: Use linux and follow README.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of searching, I have send mail to linphone forums and I got the following reply :

Building linphone is not supported on windows machine and you have to build it on mac or linux